# Creating additional value to inform what line was not predicted correctly

Tags: weka

I am trying to predict images from a bunch of pixel data on my arff file.
So far so good, it is working fine, but when i need to check what image was not predicted correctly i dont know.

Is there a way to output the line on the "=== Predictions under cross-validation ===" ?
Or there is a way to put an text on the line (like an attribute) with the image name and then outputs on the "=== Predictions under cross-validation ===" ?

Now my output is:

```
=== Predictions under cross-validation ===

 inst#     actual  predicted error prediction ()
     1        3:3        3:3       0.964 
     2        3:3        3:3       0.984 
     3        3:3        3:3       0.947 
     4        1:1        1:1       0.981 
     5        1:1        1:1       0.979 
     6        1:1        1:1       0.96 
     7        5:5        5:5       0.986 
     8        5:5        3:3   +   0.685
```

I needed to have the line or image file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new attribute as a string called ID.

Then i called the weka with:

```
java -classpath weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -F weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RemoveType -t file -W "weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron"
```